# Minecraft 1.16 – My "display:{Lore:""}" doesn't load

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My "display:{Lore:""}" doesn't load, I think it's too big for Minecraft. If you play on Hypixel's  Skyblock, you know the Aspect Of The End. I've recreated it in Minecraft Vanilla. Here's the item description :
[image: AOTE Description]

And here's the command to give the sword :

```
give NoEnd_ minecraft:diamond_sword{display:{Name:'{"text":"Aspect Of The End","italic":"false","color":"blue"}',Lore:['[{"text":"Damage:","italic":"false","color":"gray"},{"text":" +100","italic":"false","color":"red"}]','[{"text":"Strength:","italic":"false","color":"gray"},{"text":" +100","italic":"false","color":"red"}]','[{"text":"","italic":"false"}]','[{"text":"Item Ability: Instant Transmission","italic":"false","color":"gold"},{"text":" RIGHT CLICK","italic":"false","color":"yellow","bold":"true"}]','[{"text":"Teleport","italic":"false","color":"gray","bold":"false"},{"text":" 8 blocks","italic":"false","color":"lime"},{"text":" ahead of","italic","false","color":"gray"}]','[{"text":"you and gain +50","italic":"false","color":"gray"},{"text":"Speed","italic":"false","color":"white"}]','[{"text":"for","italic":"false","color":"gray"},{"text":" 5 seconds","italic":"false","color":"lime"}]']}}
```

I know this is very long.
Formatted, this code would look like:

```
give NoEnd_ minecraft:diamond_sword {
  display: {
    Name:'{"text":"Aspect Of The End","italic":"false","color":"blue"}',
    Lore: [
      '[
        {"text":"Damage:","italic":"false","color":"gray"},
        {"text":" +100","italic":"false","color":"red"}
      ]',
      '[
         {"text":"Strength:","italic":"false","color":"gray"},
         {"text":" +100","italic":"false","color":"red"}
      ]',
      '[
         {"text":"","italic":"false"}
      ]',
      '[
         {"text":"Item Ability: Instant Transmission","italic":"false","color":"gold"},
         {"text":" RIGHT CLICK","italic":"false","color":"yellow","bold":"true"}
      ]',
      '[
         {"text":"Teleport","italic":"false","color":"gray","bold":"false"},
         {"text":" 8 blocks","italic":"false","color":"lime"},
         {"text":" ahead of","italic","false","color":"gray"}
      ]',
      '[
         {"text":"you and gain +50","italic":"false","color":"gray"},
         {"text":"Speed","italic":"false","color":"white"}
      ]',
      '[
        {"text":"for","italic":"false","color":"gray"},
        {"text":" 5 seconds","italic":"false","color":"lime"}
      ]'
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't know why the lore does not load. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: As the tag wiki says, " If you want to ask for help about a command or function that does not work as you expected, please make sure to provide a "[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"."

Comment: @pppery isn't that what the command is?

Comment: Did you paste your command in a command block or in the chat?

Answer (score 1):

Are you executing the command in chat or a command block? Chat limits text to 256 characters, while for a command block there is no limit.

Comment: In the command block. Thanks for the help, but I'll use MCStacker!